# Using multiple except statement returns error outside try/except block

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except

I am using try except block in beautiful soup to get the image from a post. Try block checks if the post has a certain class if not it moves on to except. So I get this error in try block that the class does not exist. This is the simplified version of the code.

```
a = "check"

try:
    print(b)
except Exception as e:
    print(c)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
except Exception as e:
    print(a)
```

As per my understanding there should be no error and must print out "check". But I get this error ***name 'b' is not defined***

Comment: How do you want to print `b` as `check` when `a = 'check'`?

Comment: I think this is too simplified. Either you have removed too much code so that what you wrote doesn't make sense or what @Scotty1- said.

Comment: see my last except statement. My understanding is that first it checks try and it gives an error and it moves down check one by one. Then it comes to the last except statement and prints a. This is the idea I have is there a better way to do it. I can do it in if else statement. But how can i do it with try catch

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is:
**Only the `try` block is being considered in exceptions!**
If you want to catch errors raised in `except` blocks, you need to fold them into `try` blocks themselves.

Short example:

```
a = "check"

try:
    print(b)
except Exception as e:
    try:
        print(c)
    except Exception as e:
        try:
            print(e)
        except Exception as e:
            print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

What @Scotty1- says seems to be the answer for your question, however this is another way with less nested try excepts.
I was going to post this as a comment but it is a bit long so I put it here and remove it if it is wrong.

why not do something like this?

```
a = 'check'
varL = ['b', 'c', 'e', 'a']
for x in varL:
    if x in locals() or x in globals():
        exec('print({})'.format(x))
```

Note that exec is generally slower than executing normal code so if you do this make sure it is not repeated many times.